# Can you set default value of a column based on the calculations of previous two columns in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table in `SQLite` where I would like to set the value of 3rd column based on the input value of first two columns.

Does `SQLite` even support an expression in the default value of a column?

```
create table contract(
   id                primary key autoincrement,
   insurance_pct     integer not null default 0,
   historical_yield  integer not null default 0,
   guaranteed_yield  integer not null default (insurance_pct/100 * historical_yield)
)
```

When I run the above statement I see following error.

> Query execution failed
>
> Reason:
>
> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (default value of column [GUARANTEED_YIELD] is not constant)

Comment: Isn't a documentation of "CREATE TABLE"  in sqlite manual clear about it?

Comment: It does support expressions for default values, but I'm pretty sure that there's no way to refer to other columns of the row being inserted. In this case since it's so simple, just compute the value on the fly when needed (maybe in a view) instead of using a column for it.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the calculation is pretty simple and straightforward here but the point here is less code means less bugs. Why write something in your code when the vendor software can do it for you on the fly without introducing any bugs? This was a valid question related to SQLite features, not sure why it's been down voted. While I appreciate the feedback, comments and logic provided along with the answers It's just a matter of taste where the developer wants puts the business logic.

Comment: @user2325154 :: Certainly a valid question, but I disagree about the "advantage" of creating a column to store "business logic". What happens when that business logic should change at some point? You are left with a column full of useless and potentially dangerous data--that you cannot change because it is "hardwired"  to your database. You are already going to query the database with a simple SQL "SELECT"  statement. Adding the calculation to the statement should not introduce any bugs you can't introduce with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message "default value of column [GUARANTEED_YIELD] is not constant" clearly points out, you cannot use variables in the default expression.

One way to achieve what you want is to make an after insert trigger, that updates the column, when it was inserted as null. That however requires, that the column is not declared not null as otherwise the `INSERT` will fail. So you'd have to check that too in a before update trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE contract
             (id integer PRIMARY KEY
                         AUTOINCREMENT,
              insurance_pct integer
                            NOT NULL
                            DEFAULT 0,
              historical_yield integer
                               NOT NULL
                               DEFAULT 0,
              guaranteed_yield integer
                               NULL
                               DEFAULT NULL);

CREATE TRIGGER contract_ai
               AFTER INSERT
                     ON contract
               FOR EACH ROW
               WHEN (new.guaranteed_yield IS NULL)
BEGIN
  UPDATE contract
         SET guaranteed_yield = insurance_pct / 100 * historical_yield
         WHERE id = new.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER contract_bu
               BEFORE UPDATE
                      ON contract
               FOR EACH ROW
               WHEN (new.guaranteed_yield IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT raise(FAIL, 'NOT NULL constraint failed: contract.guaranteed_yield');
END;
```

One other thing I noticed: `guaranteed_yield` is an integer but your default expression pretty likely produces non integer values. You might lose something due to the required rounding. I'm not sure whether this is intentional.

---

Addendum:

Looking at the comments to your question I'm not sure whether you merely want a default -- i.e. the value of `guaranteed_yield` should have the value of the expression, if no other value is explicitly given at `INSERT` but it is possible for it to have other (non null) values either from an `INSERT` or or a subsequent `UPDATE` -- or if you intend this to be a calculated column, that always has the value the expression gives. In the latter case: I second the other commenters. This is a potentially dangerous thing regarding inconsistencies. Preferably use the expression in your queries or create a view.

Comment: @user2325154: Please also see my addendum.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in SQLite.

The [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) states :

> An explicit DEFAULT clause may specify that the default value is NULL, a string constant, a blob constant, a signed-number, or any constant expression enclosed in parentheses.

Further, the document defines the concept of *constant expression* :

> For the purposes of the DEFAULT clause, an expression is considered constant if it contains no sub-queries, column or table references, bound parameters, or string literals enclosed in double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

This namely excludes references to other columns.

Other possible approaches in your use case :

- compute the value dynamically in your DML queries (UPDATE and INSERT)
- use a trigger to provide a dynamic default on DML operations